# Dilemma with dealing with tables?

Tags: mysql, tags

I have this alogirthm problem, in terms of creating mysql tables, let me explain the scenario:

I have a a posts table:

```
Posts{id, user_id,image,tag,date}
```

each post can only have on tag! ONLY

Do I need to have another table to store tags! I can understand if each post has more than one tag, you'd have to create another table for it to store the tags! but with this  its only one!

i.e.

If I wanted to get all the posts with tag 'DOG' I would use:

```
select all posts where tag=DOG
```

do you think this is wrong or bad? I'm so confused!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If posts in your system will really only ever need to have one tag, then *technically* you can just hold the tag on the Post record. You shouldn't, though: For example, what happens when you have 250000 posts about dogs, and decide to rename the "Dog" tag to "Canine"?

A better idea is to create a Tag table and put a foreign key to it on the Post table. For example:

```
Post{post_id, user_id, image, tag_id, date}
Tag{tag_id, description}
```

But just in case you're *really* faced, someday, with a scenario in which a Post can have multiple Tags...

Then you're describing a model in which `Posts` and `Tags` exist in what's called a [Many-to-Many relationship](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_%28data_model%29): a given tag can be associated with any number of posts, and a given post can be associated with any number of tags.

Now you not only need a separate table for Tags, but a relationship table in between that relates posts to tags. For example:

```
Post{post_id, user_id, image, date}
Tag{tag_id, description}

Post_Tag{post_id, tag_id}
```

You would then select all posts with the "Dog" tag like so:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM Post p
JOIN Post_Tag pt ON pt.post_id = p.post_id
JOIN Tag t ON pt.tag_id = t.tag_id
WHERE t.description = 'Dog'
```

Comment: i understand what your saying and thank you for your answer, but one post can only be associated with one tag only! yeh thanks for the update. the tags holds an actual EVENT lol you can't be at two different events at once can you!!!

Comment: @pingpong I've updated my answer to include either scenario. I still maintain that you separate tags into their own table, even if a post can only have one. What happens if you one day decide tags should have another piece of data associated with them, like a parent tag (Dogs below Pets, for example)? Normalization for the win. :)

Comment: yeh true thats actually very true!!! i think i will create another table actually!!! +1 from me

Comment: can i ask you a question, can a tag be more than one word i.e "DOGS are Black" im sure it will work?

Comment: @pingpong Assuming the tag is just a `VARCHAR` or similar field... I can't imagine a technical reason why that wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1):

djacobson is correct when he says you need to design for possible future scenarios. Always try to keep your tables as One-to-Many if possible. For your situation however, you might be able to use a single table if you know for certain that there will never ever be more than one tag for each post. Using one table will obviously decrease your database size as well as simplify your queries. However, if you find that there could be posts that do not have any tags, you are then running the risk of having lots of NULL values in your table which should also be avoided. It would then be better to use a One-to-One relationship between a Post and Tag table, or even better, a One-to-Many relationship as explained earlier.